# Safari does not show Noto Sans fonts on a mac, while Chrome does

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, safari, google-noto

Safari does not display Noto Sans fonts which are locally installed on a Big Sur mac (M1 MacBook air). What should be wrong?

The test html code is as follows:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { font-family: "Noto Sans"; }
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and runs away.
</body>
</html>
```

The strange thing is: In Safari, Version 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9), the page is rendered with default serif font, rather than Noto Sans.

In Chrome (87.0.4280.88) on the same machine, the above html code shows Noto Sans correctly. Also, when "Noto Sans" in the above html code is replaced with some other fonts (e.g. "Arial" or "Helvetica"), it works correctly in both Safari and Chrome.

The Noto Sans fonts were downloaded from Google Fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans, and installed on my mac as .otf files.

Installing the font for the current user only and for all users didn't make any difference.

How can this be fixed for Safari? Any comments will be appreciated greatly!